# jsTree library - Why i cant create more than one nested nodes?

Tags: javascript, jstree

I've never used this library before and i'm still learning it. So i found a way to append nodes to already created tree by using a function. I'm using this function to append children nodes to already created main nodes or to create main nodes by myself.

But the problem is that i can create only one children node and cant create a children node to the children node. Here is my code :

```
$(function () {
    $('#jstree').jstree({
        'plugins': ["contextmenu", "dnd", "state"],
        'core': {
            'data': [{
                "id": "1",
                "text": "1",
                "state": {
                    "opened": false
                }
            }],
            'check_callback': true
        }

    });
});

$('#jstree').on('ready.jstree', function (e, data) {
        createNode("#1", "11", "1.1", "last");
    createNode("#jstree", "2", "2", "last");
        createNode("#2", "21", "2.1", "last");
            createNode("#21", "211", "2.1.1", "last");
    createNode("#jstree", "3", "3", "last");
        createNode("#3", "31", "3.1", "last");
        createNode("#3", "32", "3.2", "last");
            createNode("#32", "321", "3.2.1", "last");
            createNode("#32", "322", "3.2.2", "last");
        createNode("#3", "33", "3.3", "last");
    createNode("#jstree", "4", "4", "last");
        createNode("#4", "41", "4.1", "last");

});


function createNode(parent_node, new_node_id, new_node_text, position) {
    $('#jstree').jstree('create_node', $(parent_node), { "text":new_node_text, "id":new_node_id }, position, false, false);
}
```

So my problem is that nodes with id : 211, 321, 322 are not rendered on the browser and there is no errors threw on the console.

Do i miss something ? Maybe some property of the library that i dont know about it and i should add it to the JSON when i'm calling the jstree() function to create the main tree ?

P.S. SOLVED :

Anyway i found a more clever way to make it flexible.

```
var jsonDataMain = {
    'plugins': ["contextmenu", "dnd", "state"],
    'core': {
        'check_callback': true,
        'data': [{
            "id": "1",
            "text": "1",
            "children": [{
                "text": "1.1",
                "id": "11"
            },
                {
                    "text": "1.2",
                    "id": "12"
                },
                {
                    "text": "1.3",
                    "id": "13"
                },
                {
                    "text": "1.4",
                    "id": "14"
                }]
        },
            {
                "id" : "2",
                "text" : "2",
                "children": [{
                    "text": "2.1",
                    "id": "21"
                },
                    {
                        "text": "2.2",
                        "id": "22"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "2.3",
                        "id": "23",
                        "children": [{
                            "text" : "2.3.1",
                            "id" : "231",
                            "children": [{
                                "text" : "2.3.1.1",
                                "id" : "2311"
                            }]
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "2.4",
                        "id": "24"
                    }]
            }]
    }

};

$(function () {
    $('#jstree').jstree(jsonDataMain);
});

$('#jstree').on('rename_node.jstree', function (e, data) {

    jsonDataMain.core.data.push({
        "id": "3",
        "text": "3",
        "children": [{
            "text": "3.1",
            "id": "31"
        }]
    });

    $('#jstree').jstree(true).settings.core.data = jsonDataMain.core.data;
    $('#jstree').jstree(true).refresh();

});
```

So in this case i have a object. I call the jsTree function and i'm giving this object as argument.

After that when i catch some event (in this case its the rename event of contextmenu) i'm just adding some new node to the object.core.data and when the event is triggered the node is added to the tree with this two lines

```
$('#jstree').jstree(true).settings.core.data = jsonDataMain.core.data;
$('#jstree').jstree(true).refresh();
```

Of course if you want to keep the new added node to the three when you refresh your page you will need to keep the object that is used to create the tree in some kind of DataBase or something outside this JS file and when changing it to use something like PUT request, change it and then you will keep the changes.

I think this is a good way to create your tree and change it in advance. I hope i will help to someone with my solutions.

Comment: Is using createNode function a requirement? I guess you don't want to populate data from JSON ?

Comment: no its not requirement, i can do it by adding the data every node in the JSON but i want do it this way cuz its more flexible but i dont know if its possible.